# Python Django ModelForm, how can I modify a form fields before rendering it depending on the model

Tags: django, forms

Using a ModelForm, the model contains a value of a field I should render in the form :

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=256) # this contains the type of the form's field for example a CharField or a DateTimeField
```

My view :

```
class MyView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomForm
    model = MyClass
```

And the form class:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = ?
```

How can I dynamically set my form's field type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd list out all the possible fields you may need in `fields = ()` then you can remove fields you don't want, change if fields are required etc, based on the value of the model field like this;

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            if self.instance.my_field == 'value':
                del self.fields['my_field']  # remove 'my_field'
                self.fields['name'].required = False  # change required value

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = (
            'name',
            'address',
            'my_field',
            'some_other_field'
        )
```

So from your view, if you want to get a value to your form you can do something like;

```
my_object = MyClass.objects.first()
form = MyForm(instance=my_object)
context['form'] = form
# etc, etc
```

Then you can get values from fields on that object like I suggested above.

You could also just pass arbitrary args/kwargs to your forms if you need to (say you don't actually have an object to check the values from, but instead want to just pass something based on other data;

```
# in a view;
form = MyForm(my_var='something')

# in the form;
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_var = kwargs.pop('my_var')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if my_var == 'value':
            del self.fields['my_field']  # remove 'my_field'
```

Comment: I have not managed to access self.instance.my_field, django returns a "MyClass has no my_field"

Comment: That was an example. I made up the fields. Use the fields you've got on your model. Also, `instance` only exists if your form is editing a model instance. If you're not editing a model instance, where else would you get the value which is supposed to affect what fields are included?

Comment: You are right I was using the wrong fields for my Model Class, now I am using the right field but all fields in self.instance.my_field are None

Comment: It is probably due to how I am getting the infos in my view

Comment: @aze I've updated the answer to show how to pass an instance to a form or just pass some kwargs